Oracle DB ORA-01017 Error in application but not in db tool, how to debug
I have an Oracle 19c database setup in AWS RDS. To connect to it from my local computer, I need to create an SSH tunnel like this:

ssh -N -i ~/rsa_key -L 127.0.0.1:1522:db-dev.gc.net:1522 me@gateway.dev.gc.net

From here, I use the following jdbc connection to connect to my dev db:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1522:DV

When I do that from DataGrip it works just fine:

But I need to connect to this db from my locally running Spring Boot Java 11 application where I am getting the following error:

ERROR restartedMain c.z.h.p.HikariPool:594 - HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

I am literally copy and pasting the exact same username/password into both DataGrip and in my code.
Here are the details from various project files:
build.gradle
dependencies {
    api 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.1.3.RELEASE"
}

application.yml
core:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=DV)))
    username: dbuser
    password: dbpassword
    platform: oracle
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

I have checked the db parameters
NAME                     TYPE     VALUE
------------------------ -------- ------------------------------
sec_case_sensitive_logon boolean  TRUE

I have checked the users in the DBA_USERS table
[
  {
    "USERNAME": "dbuser",
    "USER_ID": 21,
    "PASSWORD": null,
    "ACCOUNT_STATUS": "OPEN",
    "LOCK_DATE": null,
    "EXPIRY_DATE": null,
    "PASSWORD_VERSIONS": "11G 12C ",
    "EDITIONS_ENABLED": "N",
    "AUTHENTICATION_TYPE": "PASSWORD"
  }
]

My question is, is there any way to have the ssh tunnel log the credentials being passed, or use wireshark to monitor the credentials being sent through the tunnel OR view Oracle db logs in AWS that can show the username/password being used to authenticate?
My guess is that the jdbc driver in the Spring Boot app is somehow manipulating the provided password in the application.yml file before sending it, e.g.; upper or lower casing it.
Have setup wireshark to listen in on tcp.dstport == 1522 but unable to see any credentials being logged that I can use to validate.

Your build has a dependency for ojdbc11, but are you sure you're using that (or at least a 19c-compatible version) at runtime? And have you tried other dialects?

From the database, check SELECT * FROM DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL;. Most Oracle databases store invalid login attempts, and the audit trail may be able to help you find if the username got scrambled somehow.

@AlexPoole I'm fairly positive it's not because of the ojdbc dependency because I'm able to successfully connect via the app and ssh tunnel to another instance of the exact same database that's using the same oracle version/image

@JonHeller Already did that and it was fairly uninformative. It just showed that I had a LOGON event with an username of dbuser and got a return code of 1017. Which is the same thing as the ORA-01017 error in the app logs. I'm not able to see the actual password that's being used to authenticate

You won't be able to see the password. It is never transmitted in clear text. It is hashed using a one way hash function by the client and the hash is sent encrypted over the network. The literal password never leaves the client. Is it possible that one database has different hashing level requirements than the other? Compare SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION on both databases.

@pmdba that makes sense. I'm not sure if I will have access to the ora files to be able to check the SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION files but will try.
But how does that explain why I am able to connect to that db via DataGrip but not via the Spring Boot app?

@SamuelAlito In older versions of Oracle, the passwords were case insensitive. Despite your database parameter, if the user was created a long time ago, the database might still have a copy of the case-insensitive hash. Your password might actually be wrong everywhere, but if one of your systems is configured to only send the old, case insensitive hash, it would work for only that client.

Show your datasource configuration (the java part) you only provide the yaml, which isn't the default Spring datasource so you are configuring a custom datasource. Also why aren't you using the same JDBC url here but the long winded one?

@JonHeller sure but that still doesn't explain how copy pasting the same password into my app vs DataGrip results in the former not working but the latter working. It feels like Spring/Java/OJDBC is doing something to the password that DataGrip is not
